# How to get the icon of the remote device in Control point by UPnP?

Tags: android, upnp

I implement a UPnP Control point in android platform using the org.cybergarage.upnp.ControlPoint. I can get the DMS and DMR device, but I don't know how to get the icon of the remote device. I can get the URL of icon(), but how to get the icon file with the URL.The URL likes this: /img/icon-S5.png. I search the upnp stack which implement by org.cybergarage.upnp, but I can't find the relevant API about it. Please give me some advice.

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific UPnP API you could find, because it's simply a standard HTTP URL in context of the device. You get the image by HTTP request like with any other plain webserver. So if the icon URL is `/img/icon-S5.png` and the device is listening at, say `192.168.1.42:7564`, you must do an HTTP GET request for `http://192.168.1.42:7564/img/icon-S5.png`.  I don't know the cybergarage API, but it should provide you the image size and MIME too, so that you don't need to guess or parse the image before displaying it.